# Cannot call file through jupyter using open()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, filepath

This question seems to be asked occasionally, but the usual answer of "use an absolute path" does not work. Need to know how to proceed next.

Relative path

```
f = open('test.txt')
```

and absolute path

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\*myname*\\test.txt')
```

both yield [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

If I use single backslashes or remove "C:" as I have seen it written elsewhere I get [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:

Yes the file is definitely in that directory, I've checked a dozen times. How am I being stupid please? I would like to learn how to code beyond the 3rd lesson.

Thank you.

Comment: do you run jupyter on your computer or on server ? If on server then it has access only to files on sever.

Comment: BTW: file can be in one directory but Jupyter can use different directory as "Current Working Directory" (CWD). You can try to check it with `os.getcwd()`

Comment: I am running it from my computer. After I 'import os' then 'os.getcwd()' works. It shows directory 'C:\\Users\\*myname*\\' Exactly where my file is located. But I still get "No such file or directory" when I try the open function again.

Comment: did you try `os.listdir()` to see what files can see script ?

Comment: Thank you, when I ran this command it listed everything including my file which was named test.txt.txt - I was unaware of the extra .txt

Comment: you can describe problem with `test.txt.txt` as answer. It can be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly want to access file like " open('test.txt') ", make sure that this file exists in the directory from where you run your jupyter notebook.

Paths with double backslashes "\\" work in windows environment. If you are using Linux, then use "/".

Use os.getcwd() to get your current working directory and use the path accordingly.

Comment: I am using windows. The file does exist and I have used the 'os.getcwd()' to find cwd. Either way, using an absolute path should work, but it isn't?